# JQGrid server pagination not working

Tags: jqgrid, pagination

Client side pagination is working for me(that was very easy). 
I have a method in the server side that will accept pagenumber and number of records.
When I display the grid for the first time, for example I get 15 records, I also set the pagenumber, totalpages. if I have 40 records, it should say "view 1-15 of 40", "page 1 of 3". 
I set the attributes like this.

```
$("#sampleGrid").jqGrid({
loadonce:false,
page: 1,
rowNum: 15,
TotalPages: 3,
onPaging: {
if(pgbutton == "next_gridpager"){
//call the server side method. pass pagenumber and number of records as parameter
}
else if(pgbutton == "prev_gridpager")
{
 //call server side method to get data
}
});
```

The problem is even though I specify the page to be displayed and Totalpages, it shows only first page. how do i tell jqgrid that it is not client side pagination and please set the totalpages to 3.

Answer (score 1):

You provide too little information about your problem. What data you received from the server? It must look like:

`{"total":3,"page":1,"records":40,"rows":[your data...]}`.

You don't need to use parameter `TotalPages`  and `onPaging` event in  jqGrid config, if reply from server is correct, pagination will work, to enable server side pagination you need to set `datatype` and `url` parameter

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I figured out the issue. It was because I was not returning data properly.